# Regexp to remove lines matching a substring containing alternative words in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba

The idea is to filter a column F containing many strings and to remove the strings that are not matching the "acceptable substrings".

Using this function:

```
Public Function RegExReplace(Str As String, Pattern As String, _
                         ReplaceWith As String, _
                         Optional ReplaceAll As Boolean = False _
                         ) As String
                         
Dim Matches As Object
Dim RegEx As Object

Set RegEx = New RegExp

RegEx.Pattern = Pattern

' Set by user
RegEx.Global = ReplaceAll

RegExReplace = RegEx.Replace(Str, ReplaceWith)

 End Function
```

I've created the following list of acceptable substrings that should remain (by deleting those that do not match) in the right cell (G82; and through out the G column on the right):

=regexreplace($F82,"[PDAP-[^(PGFGEN|IASIL|MWSL|ROL|SCA|ICIL|3MI|VIIL|MWIL|)].*","",TRUE)

When applying a specific regexp to my excel's left column (F), it mostly works but for some cells that contain a substring starting with some letters (I,G) that are in my initial regexp filter. So I guess I've made a mistake in declaring words.. as the first two occurences should not appear from the list (the rest is fine).
Yet I do not find the proper "word" declaration!

Any help welcome

So to be clear, from the right column, these two lines are extra and should also be removed:
[PDAP-GSTMC-TRD-REQ-021]
[PDAP-IOT-TRD-REQ-023]

See results here:
[image: Sample & result columns]

Comment: Hint: `[^(PGGE)]` = `[^PGE()]`.

Comment: Do you have some markdown sample data for us to work with, explaining what exactly should match and why? Note that you haven't escaped the outer brackets making the whole thing a character class too.

Comment: This has got an excellent regex tester - you can dump all your input data in there and test your regex expression https://regex101.com/

Comment: check this - https://imgur.com/a/KBui5r3 your 2 provided items match